# Simplifying assembly code generated from gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly

I wanted to demonstrate how different C functions get turned into ARM assembly code using gcc, so I tried compiling this function

```
int f(int a) {
  return a+1;
}
```

using the command:

```
gcc -O3 -S test.c
```

to get:

```
        .arch armv6
        .eabi_attribute 27, 3
        .eabi_attribute 28, 1
        .fpu vfp
        .eabi_attribute 20, 1
        .eabi_attribute 21, 1
        .eabi_attribute 23, 3
        .eabi_attribute 24, 1
        .eabi_attribute 25, 1
        .eabi_attribute 26, 2
        .eabi_attribute 30, 2
        .eabi_attribute 18, 4
        .file   "test.c"
        .text
        .align  2
        .global f
        .type   f, %function
f:
        @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
        @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
        @ link register save eliminated.
        add     r0, r0, #1
        bx      lr
        .size   f, .-f
        .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) 4.6.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

However, this gives a whole lot of extra side information that looks a bit intimidating to a novice.  Is there a way to tell gcc to emit more concise assembly?  My ideal would be something like:

```
f:
        add     r0, r0, #1
        bx      lr
```

but anything shorter would be helpful.

I tried looking through the options [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) and tried using -g0, but it gave the same output.

Comment: you can put the output through `grep` and simply remove all lines staring with `.`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing at the moment, but it felt like there should be a proper set of options in gcc that still results in legal code - perhaps I'm wrong